# Trying remove function with enumerate in loops

Tags: python, loops, enumerate

I am currently learning python, and I recently knowing there is function called **enumerate**, so I try to get myself better understanding by figuring out another way to solve this problem from Coursera. Whats happen is I am trying to use **remove function to modify the list after duplicating the original list**, so the **for loops** does not confused (it iterates the original, but I modify the duplicate list). Can anyone maybe knowing whats wrong with my code? Thanks before for the help.

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    # code goes here
    #new_elements=[]
    dup = elements
    for count, val in enumerate(elements):
        #if count % 2 == 0:
        #   new_elements.append(val)
        if count % 2 == 1:
            dup.remove(val)
    #return new_elements
    return dup

print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])) 
# Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])) 
# Should be ['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']
```

Comment: You have not duplicated the list. You just created a new reference to the same list. Use `elements[:]` to create a shallow copy.

Comment: `dup = elements.copy()`. Read more about what @KlausD. mentioned about it being reference [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: if on a runining iterator on a list, you dont remove the element from that list. what happen is if you remove element then iterator skip the next element (next of removed element) and goes to next to next element

Comment: @rangoow please format the code inside of the function definition, you are missing the indentation, and right now this code spinets is not valid python code

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. that solve my problem!

Comment: @Ch3steR thank you too for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have not duplicated the list. You just created a new reference to the same list. Use elements[:] to create a shallow copy. -@KlausD
>
> dup = elements.copy(). Read more about what @KlausD. mentioned about it being reference Facts and myths about Python names and values – Ch3steR

After a slight reading from mr Ch3steR's [reference](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), basically this part of the code **dup = elements** did not copy or duplicate the original list, but only referencing the same list, thats why if I edit (remove) that same list, it will go chaos. The solution is using **elements[:]** or **dup = elements.copy()**.

Great Thanks to [@KlausD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) and [@Ch3steR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster) from the comment.